# How do I set the password using a variable for a SSIS 2005 web service connection?

Tags: database, web-services, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have a Web Service and I need to set the user name and password to be able to consume this service..

The webservice works fine when I run it locally, however this does not occur on the server since the password is lost when the package is transferred on another server.

I want to know whether it is possible to set the password through a variable? I tried to use the connection expression but was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

When saving the SSIS package set the 'Package protection level' to 'Do not save sensitive data'.  To add a configuration file the package needs to be added to a Visual Studio project.  In Visual Studio's SSIS menu select 'Package Configurations' and add a configuration file to your project and select the connections to include.  Then you can deploy the package and config file to your production server.

Comment: my problem is that i cannot set the username and password credentials for the http connection manager dynamically though for example a variable.. was wondering whether there was a way to set the connection string through an expression

Comment: The ServerPassword property is not exposed in the expression properties for an http connection manager.  It is exposed in a configuration file so I think you are stuck using that.